# Efficient way to update the values of a given range of cells in an array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

A have a set of lights -> l1, l2, l3, l4,.....lx etc.

At any given point in time, only a contiguous sequence of lights is on. For example:

l2,l3,l4 can be on. Or l9,l10,l11 can be on.
But it is not possible to have a gap in between. For example, you can't have l3,l7,l8.

At every tick of the clock, I'm told which are the starting and finishing lights in the sequence, and I need to make sure only the lights within the range are on. (This means I may have to switch on or off lights, depending on which lights were on and off in the previous tick. If lights are already on or off, then I don't need to update those lights.).

What is the quickest way to compute which lights to turn on and off ?
I've come up with a number of solutions, but cannot decide which is best:

1. Linear approach:
   In this solution, I iterate through all the lights from l0...lx. I check if each light is in the range. If it is, I make sure its on, if not, I make sure its off. This is simple to implement, but is wasteful if there are no changes, and worse, if the range is towards the end (e.g.: l9,l10,l11 etc)
2. Series of if's:
   In this approach, I keep track of the start / end of the range in the previous tick of the clock, and compare it with the range from the current tick.

   - If the ranges are same, do nothing. (ls,us)
   - If lower limit increases, turn of lights till new lower limit. (li)
   - if upper limit increases, turn on lights till new upper limit. (ui)
   - If lower limit decreases, turn on lights from new lower limit to old (ld)
   - if upper limit decreases, turn off lights from old upper limit to new upper limit. (ud). As you can see, in approach (2), there are nine possible combinations of changes. So the second approach has a lot of if's, and so it is unclear to me what the best way to code this (have 9 if else blocks ?- seems messy):

   li,ui li,us li,ud
   ls,ui ls,us ls,ud
   ld,ui ld,us ld,ud
3. Pointer approach - In this approach, I create arrays of both the ranges..

Eg: array 1: {3,4,5}
    array 2: {4,5,6,7}

I use p,q to point to the current cell in each array that I am observing.

I start reading from the lowest index of both arrays
If array1[p] < array2[q] , then I turn of the light at index array1[p], and increment p
If array1[p] == array2[q] , then I increment p and q, since the light is already on.
if array1[p] > array2[q] , then I turn on the light at array2[q], and increment q.
I can optimise this approach, by checking if the start / finish index is the same.

I think approach 3 is the best - since the code is easiest to read and seems quick.
I can implement all 3, but can't decide which approach is best. Would appreciate suggestions on better methods, or how to choose from these three and optimise them. Either C or C++ can be used in my app.

EDIT: The ranges in two consecutive ticks could be far apart and differ in size.. Eg: Tick 1 could be {3,4,5} and tick 2 could be {7,8,9,10}. So in this example, I would have to switch off lights at 3,4,5 and then turn on at 7,8,9,10.

EDIT: "Lights" are an analogy I'm using to explain the problem. Lights just refer to an object in software.

EDIT: I have access to only one thread, so cannot parallelise any part of this.

Comment: How many lights do you have?

Comment: @MattCoubrough There could be an arbitrary number of lights, but the number of lights is fixed for the duration of application execution. You could assume that it is some known value "n"

Comment: Unless you have millions of lights, or incredibly limited memory to work with, then simply use a linear data structure. Walk it at every cycle, toggling those that need to be toggled. I would never advocate optimizing until you have a working solution and can prove that it is the bottleneck in your code.

Comment: @john Could there *really* be *any* number of lights? From 1 to 2 ^ 16 (or even 2 ^ 32)?

Comment: Aah, i guess I didn't see it from your perspectives. There would be at most 100s of lights. I'm trying to find the fastest solution because the devices I'm running on are resource constrained. All three solutions above would work, but I feel I'm not experienced enough to pick the best solution of the three above.

Comment: @John From your (detailed) question I get: You **are** experienced enough to just try it out. All of the solutions provided by you or any answer. We believe in you. You can do it, John! Go on! Show them!

Comment: :) Thanks I will profile all the solutions. I apologise, for not doing that in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a contrived problem, or are you physically controlling lights via a port?

The fact that there's only ever one contiguous sequence to keep track of makes this an easy problem.  The best, I would say, is option 2.  Something like this should handle all cases of overlapping and non-overlapping ranges:

```
if( old_right < new_left || old_left > new_right ) {
    // Non-overlapping
    for( int i = old_left; i <= old_right; i++ ) set_light_state( i, OFF );
    for( int i = new_left; i <= new_right; i++ ) set_light_state( i, ON );
} else {
    // Overlapping
    for( int i = old_left; i < new_left; i++ ) set_light_state( i, OFF );
    for( int i = new_left; i < old_left; i++ ) set_light_state( i, ON );
    for( int i = old_right+1; i <= new_right; i++ ) set_light_state( i, ON );
    for( int i = new_right+1; i <= old_right; i++ ) set_light_state( i, OFF );
}
```

This solution should only modify those lights that are necessary, with minimal loss to branch-prediction inefficiency (if that matters).  I am assuming that the problem to solve is minimizing the number of state changes.

Comment: I don't actually have lights, but the easiest way to explain the problem is using this analogy. :). The state changes are necessary (cannot be minimised), since each tick I need to make sure only the correct range of lights is on. The problem is finding the quickest way to figure out which lights to turn on and off, given only the ranges from the previous tick and the current tick.

Comment: This will do it for you.  It only modifies those lights that need a state change.  I haven't handled the first case (where no lights are on and no range is set, but you could achieve that using an inverted range such as -1 to -2).  If you can turn on or off an entire range at once, you could adjust this code as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the approach that is

- easiest to **read** (because readability is important) and
- easiest to **implement** (because you want a quick result / feedback)

Then do profiling. If this algorithm is sufficient then you are done. If not, move on to the next approach.

Comment: Best answer to this question so far.

Answer (score 1):

Well, because this question piqued my interest the most today, and assuming this is simply a thought exercise, I've come up with some code...

The criteria I applied (not 100% sure if this exactly matches the original poster's requirements):

1. only iterate through lights that require a state change
2. minimize data needing to be stored
3. never turn any light ON that is already On.
4. never turn any light OFF that is already Off.
5. assume the turnOn() and turnOff() methods are potentially expensive

First of all, observe that between any two light updates, one of 7 possible state changes takes place as shown by this rudimentary picture:

[image: diagram of light state changes]

1. the lights turning on are entirely inside the current range of lights that are on.
2. the lights turning on completely overlap the whole sequence that is currently on.
3. the lights turning on overlap the start of the sequence that is currently on.
4. the lights turning on overlap the end of the sequence that is currrently on.
5. the lights turning on are all entirely before the current range of lights that are on.
6. the lights turning on are all entirely after the current range of lights that are on.
7. all the lights are being turned off

**And here is my implementation...**

We keep track only of the start and end range of lights that are currently on (in the member variables *start* and *end*).

Note that all ranges includes start but exclude end, so if start=2 and end=5 that means lights 2,3, and 4 are on.

```
int start;
int end;

void Switcher::toggleLights(int new_start, int new_end) {

    if( new_start > start && new_end < end ) {
        //case 1: new lights are within range of lights that are already on           
        turnOffRange(start, new_start);       
        turnOffRange(new_end, end);                     
    }       
    else if( new_start < start && new_end > end) {
        //case 2: lights already on are entirely within new range       
        turnOnRange(new_start, start);
        turnOnRange(end, new_end);           
    }
    else if( new_start < start && new_end > start ) {
        //case 3: new light sequence overlaps start of current range
        turnOffRange(new_end, end);
        turnOnRange(new_start, start);            
    }
    else if( new_start < end && new_end > end ){
        //case 4: new light sequence overlaps end of current range
        turnOffRange(start, new_start);
        turnOnRange(end, new_end);            
    }   
    else {
        //case 5,6 or 7 (no overlap at all)
        turnOffRange(start,end);       
        turnOnRange(new_start,new_end); 
    }

    // keep track of the lights that are now on
    start = new_start;
    end = new_end;
}

void Switcher::turnOffRange(int from, int to) {
    for(int i=from; i < to; ++i) {
        turnOff(i); // (potentially expensive) method to turn light off
    }
}

void Switcher::turnOnRange(int from, int to) {
    for(int i=from; i < to; ++i) {
        turnOn(i); // (potentially expensive) method to turn lamp on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as the question is formulated now, my first thought would be to just use the starting and finishing lights directly in a loop.

```
for (i = startinglight ; i <= finishinglight ; i++){
    lightarray[i-1] * turn on lights * ;
}
```

...but since this is very easy, maybe I am missing something in the question
(it also only works of course if the numbers of the lights in the array starts at 1 and is continuous)

Comment: I agree that a linear approach is simple, readable and effective, although it looks as if this solution isn't turning off the lights that need to be turned off.

Comment: Matt is correct, your solution doesn't turn off the lights that need to be turned off. Two consecutive ticks could have very different ranges. Eg: {2,3,4} followed by {7,8,9}. So in this case, you would have to turn off {2,3,4} and then turn on {7,8,9}

Comment: @MattCoubrough : indeed, you got me :) (I knew I was missing something basic)

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure to bit-pack the values, i.e. instead of doing i.e.

```
bool lightStatus[NUMBER_OF_LIGHTS];
```

do

```
uint64_t lightStatus[(NUMBER_OF_LIGHTS + 63) / 64];
```

assuming you're on a 64-bit processor. Else, use `uint32_t`. This will make sure you waste no bits when reading/writing, since all bits of `lightStatus` are really used to encode the status of a light.

It will also make it very efficient to clear all the lights, by just doing a `memset()` of the entire array. That will be probably be fast enough to work even though you risk doing needless clears.

Regarding the update, I'd do the obvious, since it's basically the core information anyway: store the current range, so that whenever you get a new one you can clear precisely the old one. If it turns out to be a bottleneck you can get fancy and eliminate the overlap of course but I wouldn't worry unless this is running on a seriously slow CPU or there are (many?) thousands of lights.

Comment: This seems useful (and I will incorporate it), but the biggest part of my problem is figuring out which lights to turn on and off, given only the range of lights that must be on in the current tick. (I can store the range from the previous tick (start / finish index).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be a combination of a for loop and an if statement:

where X is total number of lights

```
int lightArray[X] = {0};
int startLight;
int endLight;

for (int i = 0, i < X, i++){
    if (i >= startLight && i <= endLight){
        if (lightArray[i] == 0){                 
            lightArray[i] = 1; // or you can change the lights in this loop
        }
    }
    else{
        lightArray[i] = 0; // or you can change the lights in this loop
    }
} 

for (int i = 0, i < x, i++){
    //some function that sets lights on and off based on lightArray[i]
}
```

Comment: This looks a lot like my solution (1), so I'm not sure if I've misunderstood. Although this is simple, isn't it wasteful, since I iterate through the entire array each time ?

Comment: It is slightly wasteful. If you notice the comments you could do it in a single iteration by adding the code for setting the lights status in the first for loop. along with setting the array (used to check current status of lights)

Comment: Branching inside a loop using constants like this is extremely wasteful.  Iterating over the entire array *with* branching is insane!  You may as well change it to three loops over the entire array with no branching...  But then, you miss the point of the question.

Comment: The time it takes to iterate through an array is utterly insignificant when compared to the time it takes to actually physically trigger a light relay, dimmer or send a DMX message to a lighting controller.

Comment: @MattCoubrough I don't recall any part of the question that mentions application to stage lighting.  The OP just wants to flip light states.  This answer only handles half of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your lights in an array of binary values `{0,1}`, say `ar`

Then if `[first, last)` is the range where the the lights are on, you split the array in 3 ranges [begin, first), [first, last), [last, end), (where each of each range can be empty).

```
begin = &ar[0];
end   = &ar[N];
```

Finally you run an operation for each elememt on each range

```
for_each(begin, first, [](int i) { i &= 0x0; });
for_each(first, last , [](int i) { i |= 0x1; });
for_each(last,  end  , [](int i) { i &= 0x0; });
```

the first and last loop will set the state to `0` and the second loop will set the state to `1`

---

A similar solution would have all values kept in a [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) instead of an array, where you could use the member functions `set` and `flip`, but you'd again have to loop over the values of each bit.

Comment: This might be a good optimization if there is a proven bottleneck or memory limitation, but do not forget that premature optimization is the root of all evil. Furthermore, flipping individual bits is not as performant as it could be - if you know your range of lights is greater than 8 you can flip an entire byte at a time.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Yes, I'm replying in the grounds that OP wants an optimized solution, otherwise it's a `for` with an `if` and plain assignments

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood, but in this solution aren't we effectively iterating through the entire range of lights again ?

Comment: @John Yes, but it buys you a branchless iteration (no `if` in the loop) and a fast operation to set the values. Further optimization would require you to unroll the loops. Finally splitting into 3 ranges would give the chance to do each operation in parallel (ofcourse this would have meaning for very very very large subsets - again I'm supposing that's the case otherwise what Matt said applies)